# Can't implement blind effect jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got working examples of this blind effect, and of course they work fine, but I don't seem to be able to adapt it to my code. I've extracted the relevant bits so it will look a bit odd.

My code is to do with the adding of a new div for the new line in a chat room, the code works well, however when i add a `display:none` or `display:hidden` to the div and then `$.show` it, it does not use the blind effect.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisadmin/wmp26w97/1/

Here is the code:

```
var ngcClientTag = 999;
var innerHtml = '<div style="position:relative; display:hidden; font-size:50px;" id="s_m_' + ngcClientTag + '"></div><div style="clear:both"></div>';

var message = "heeeeeeelllllllllloooooooooooooooooooooooooo";

$("#newMsg").append(innerHtml);
$("#s_m_" + ngcClientTag).text(message).show("blind", {
    direction: "vertical"
}, 3000);
```

[EDIT]
jquery and jqueryui scripts included in the jsfiddle example

Comment: You should load additional plugin for animation effects.

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI to enable this effect? http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: ofcourse - look at the jsfiddle includes jquery and ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine for me once i changed `display:hidden` to `display:none`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmp26w97/3/

Comment: damn i tried that, although it was a slightly more complicated example. I think probably artm has the answer both ways however

Comment: Nope i recind that comment, its nothing to do with toggle and all to do with display:none;

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wmp26w97/2/

Start with `display:none`

and use `.toggle("blind"`